# Vue: How to load a file from a dynamic path

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component named Item :

```
<template>
    <div :id="item.slug" class="item" :data-position="item.position">
        <div class="hero" :style="heroPath"></div>
        <div class="text">{{ textData }}</div>
        <div class="back_link">
            <a @click="back">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This component receives a few parameters, including **slug**. I'd like the  to be populated with the content of an external file (.vue or .html preferrably). How can I achieve this, since the component doesn't know right away what its **slug** is going to be ?

I initially tried to do the import like

```
import textData from '@/content/'+item.slug+'.vue'
```

but this obviously doesn't work...
I tried doing a similar thing within created()

```
created () {
    this.textData = import('@/content/'+item.slug+'.vue')
}
```

Still no cookie.
I'm inexperienced with Vue.component and with require.context so maybe the solution is there and I haven't spent enough time on it ?

Thank you !

Comment: you will face the problem because there's no server side rendering in SPA, so you will need something like Nuxt to update and load data again after loaded because files already loaded once, if you need to load another data or change in inspect elements you will need to client side rendreing, check [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/)

Comment: Use [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) with `<component :is="" />` and pass the desired dynamic component directly as a prop.